# How to display the background image behind heading text?

Tags: html, css, background-image, html-heading

I have an image strip and I have to display that image as a background of my heading.

I tried but I am getting one issue and the issue is, the first edge and last edge are not displaying properly. I mean starting image and end images are not displaying properly. Also, image border displaying straight.

```css
.red_strip {
  background-image: url('http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/basekit-template-images/hostgator443_hostgator574_headergreenbgpaint.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <span class="red_strip">labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>


  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod <span class="red_strip">tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>

  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /><span class="red_strip"> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>


</div>
```

Comment: To prevent cuting of you image you need background-size `contain`

Comment: add `padding: 0 15px` to  `.red_strip`.

Comment: I tried to contain but it's not working as expected. It's displaying link https://prnt.sc/q8nhix

Comment: just remove 'background-size: cover;' from '.red_strip' class, this should solve your problem

Comment: Did you check your code by adding padding?

Comment: @PullataPraveen, Yes, I checked using padding, it's giving some space from left to right but the border of the image is show straight which is not correct.

Comment: @NarenVerma First thing is that you should never use that much size of image for `inline-block` elements. My suggestion for you is to reduce the width and height of an image and try.

Comment: @NarenVerma I hope my answer will work for u. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261697/how-to-display-the-background-image-behind-heading-text/59261956#59261956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `red_strip` class as

```
.red_strip {
  background-image: url(http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/basekit-template-images/hostgator443_hostgator574_headergreenbgpaint.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

`background-size: 100% 100%;` property will stretch the background image horizontally and vertically

```css
.red_strip {
  background-image: url(http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/basekit-template-images/hostgator443_hostgator574_headergreenbgpaint.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <span class="red_strip">labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod <span class="red_strip">tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /><span class="red_strip"> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: give me some time to check this

Comment: @NarenVerma Okay

Comment: Yes, Your answer is working perfectly for me. Give me some time to confirm with my other heading.

Comment: @NarenVerma Okay

Answer (score 1):

This will do :

```
background-size:  102% 102%;

   .red_strip {
                    background-image: url('http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/basekit-template-images/hostgator443_hostgator574_headergreenbgpaint.png');
                    background-size: 102% 102%;
                    background-repeat: repeat;
                    background-position: center;
                    width: 100%;
                }
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: I tried your answer, It's also working but not 100% If I use 102% the changing little bit border and also I use no-repeat and remove the position. same as nitheesh answer. Upvote from my side

Comment: @NarenVerma my answer and Nitheesh's answer are the same and I answered 4 minutes prior to his .Dont know why didnt get the green tick. I used 102% so that the image contains the whole text. although, thanks!!

Comment: Yes, Your answer is first and added the explanation in the about comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `class="red_strip"` in heading tag like:

```
<h2 class="red_strip"> 
// Your text
</h2>
```

Remove `<span class="red_strip">`

Also make sure your `background-size` should be `background-size: 100% 100%`

Comment: Why red_strip is no h2 tag?

Comment: h2 act like div ie full width and span act like text, if you want to set hole h2 background use class in h2 tag, and if you want to text in background better way to use <mark> tag.

Comment: I don't want to display an image on whole h2 tag. just a small part of the h2

Comment: ok so use background-size: 100% 100%; in your red_strip class of span

Answer (score 0):

```css
.design  {
padding-left:25px;
background:url(http://www.hgsitebuilder.com/files/writeable/uploads/basekit-template-images/hostgator443_hostgator574_headergreenbgpaint.png) no-repeat top left;
display: inline-block;
background-size:100% 100%;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <span class="design">labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>


  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /> elit, sed do eiusmod <span class="design">tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>

  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing<br /><span class="design"> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></h2>


</div>
```

Comment: please check the answer